# ArcPy Detect Objects Using Deep Learning error read input raster

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, deep-learning

I am trying to do object detection with standalone script using ArcPy. The ArcGIS Pro version is 3.2.1. I made this script based on Model Builder and this documentation.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/image-analyst/detect-objects-using-deep-learning.htm

The script I use is written below.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.ia import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("ImageAnalyst")

in_models = 'model_fastrcnn.dlpk'
data_raster = 'radar.tif'  
obj_detection = 'obj.shp'
model_args = "padding 56; threshold 0.5; nms_overlap 0.1; batch_size 64; exclude_pad_detections True; test_time_augmentation False"
run_nms = "NO_NMS"
confidence_score_field = "Confidence"
class_value_field = "Class"
max_overlap_ratio = 0
processing_mode = "PROCESS_AS_MOSAICKED_IMAGE"
arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.Extent(113.7975122046781706, -7.7461582880389077, 114.0177164475001632, -7.4046301537038710)
Output_Classified_Raster = arcpy.ia.DetectObjectsUsingDeepLearning(data_raster,
                                                            obj_detection,
                                                            in_models,
                                                            model_args, 
                                                            run_nms, 
                                                            confidence_score_field, 
                                                            class_value_field, 
                                                            max_overlap_ratio, 
                                                            processing_mode)
```

When I ran this script it shows error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GIS Dev\Documents\Riset_arcpy.ia\Radarsat-2-4978_I005632_FL01-P008585_Scene_1_2023_08_20_22_01_42\tif\obj.py", line 16, in <module>
    Output_Classified_Raster = arcpy.ia.DetectObjectsUsingDeepLearning(data_raster,
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\ia\Functions.py", line 4040, in DetectObjectsUsingDeepLearning
    return Wrapper(
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 55, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\ia\Functions.py", line 4029, in Wrapper
    result = arcpy.gp.DetectObjectsUsingDeepLearning_ia(
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 520, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: A raster error has occurred. The messages that follow will provide more detail.
No raster store is configurated. [No SQL data store]
No raster store is configurated. [No SQL data store]
Failed to execute (DetectObjectsUsingDeepLearning).
```

I can't figure out the solution for this. With the same scenario it ran without error in ArcGIS Pro.